# Typescript check type against enum

Tags: typescript, union

I have two types, one is enum:

```
enum Vehicle {
   Car = 'car',
   Plane = 'plane',
}
```

The second one is regular object, which uses enum as keys:

```
type VehicleProperties = {
   [Vehicle.Car]: { amountOfWheels: number };
   [Vehicle.Plane]: { amountOfWings: number };
}
```

How would I do a type `VehicleConfig`, that unifies both of them and will satisfy:

```
const vehicle: VehicleConfig = {
   type: Vehicle.Car,
   properties: {
      amountOfWheels: 4,
   }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you have a typo: `numberOfWheels` should be `amountOfWheels`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom mapped type:

```
type VehicleConfig= {
    [P in keyof VehicleProperties]: {
        type: P,
        properties: VehicleProperties[P]
    }
}[keyof VehicleProperties]

const vehicle: VehicleConfig = {
   type: Vehicle.Car,
   properties: {
      amountOfWheels: 4
   }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAasAWBLAxgG2FA3gKCngwgIYBOUAvFAOTImUA0ueACqoSBhZQA6vv3YBfbNgAuATy4Y4SNMCbEA9pOIjEwAM7ksjKAG1pKdADoixALoAuLFEIQFYECIDyAMwDq8YMFTqr4CABGwKQCANw6+giGwEYsbMCW1rb2jq5uiCAA5r5Q-kEh4ULikrBRsvgKIC6ImRQ4eHi6TFAZUADWwGIKLqUy6PJKwaoaifUN48XAVkwM4+NcisrDOQayA0tq6k1mOlBCArodXT2r-YtDmzvYyJXqIlAAbmXoVqfAFVU1WmNQk6-PMVMszwC0GKk2Vh+DWSDmc7k83hyABYdPsgA)